# If statement that includes a infinite math equation

Tags: c#

I'm trying to execute code such that a specific infinite math condition is true. The condition is true such that the value = 90 + 360X . Where X is a integer. So i'm working with the Unit Circle and only want degress that equal the Postive Y axis. Here is a pic of the axis highlighed in orange.

[image]

For example, angles 90, 450, 810, etc would make the condition true.
I have tried using a % in my code as you can see:

```
else if (DegreeValue == 90 || ManyRotations90(DegreeValue, 90) == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Angle(" + DegreeValue + ") lies between the 1st and 2nd quadrant. In other words, it doesn't belong to a specfic section.");
        }




static public bool ManyRotations90(double num01, double num02)
    {

        if (num01 % num02 == 0);
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
```

Even though the condition would return true for those numbers, it also would for number I don't want. //this is good 540 % 90 == 0. But 270 % 90 == 0 //which is bad. Is there a way such that it's only true for  90 + 360X?

Comment: Add a second condition?

Comment: Maybe by adding `if (num01 >= 360 && num01 % num02 == 0)` ?

Comment: Why not use `value % 360 == 90`?

Comment: what is an  "infinite math condition"?

Comment: @bolov I meant a math problem that has an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: Tip: `return (num01 % num02 == 0)` is a shorter way of writing the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're misusing the `%` operator. You need to divide the number of degrees by 360 (full circles), and check if the remainder is 90:

```
return DegreeValue % 360 == 90;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! I'm also trying to get this to work with negative angles. So a negative angle work slike this: 360 + (negative angle) and that is where it would be located. So -90 is located at 270 degrees. So for -660 how would I figure out which quadrant that is in?

Comment: @Samurai The modulu (`%`) operator works just fine with negative numbers. `-660` is `360 * (-2) + 60`, which places it in the first quardrant.

Comment: Negative angles go clockwise and positive angles go counter-clockwise. So it would be in the 4th quadrant. Because we go 2 rotations to the left and another 60 degrees to the left.  So  the angle would be at 300 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to make this work with negative angles. The positive angles can be found using the solution from @Mureinik. So lets say I wanted to figure out if a negative angle was in the 3rd quadrant, how would I do that?

```
 else if (
            NegCheck(DegreeValue) == true //This just check to see if the angle is negtive
            && 360 + DegreeValue > 180
            && 360 + DegreeValue < 270
            || Between180_270(DegreeValue) == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Angle(" + DegreeValue + ") lies in the 3nd quadrant");
        }

static public bool Between180_270(double Degreevalue01)
    {

        if (NegCheck(Degreevalue01) == true)
        {
            double step = 0.0;

            step = (360 + Degreevalue01) % 360;
            step = 360 + step;
            if (step > 180 && step < 270)
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
```

So if the angle is -1175 we would add that to 360 and get -815. Then after we preform the % operation the value will be -95. Then add 360 to it we get 265. The angle 265 is indeed in the third quadrant of the unit circle. Hopefully this solution will  help someone one day.